# How to initialize correctly the ConstraintVerifier for testing Optaplanner ConstraintStreams in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, optaplanner

How can I initialize a ConstraintVerifier in Kotlin without using Drools and Quarkus?
I already added the optaplanner-test JAR and the Maven Dependency for Optaplanner 8.6.0.Final and tried it the following way:

```
var constraintVerifier : ConstraintVerifier<GroupAssignmentConstraintProvider, GroupAssignmentSolution> =
    ConstraintVerifier.build(GroupAssignmentConstraintProvider(),
        GroupAssignmentSolution::class.java,
        GroupAssignment::class.java)
```

(ConstraintProvider: GroupAssignmentConstraintProvider, Solution: GroupAssignmentSolution, PlanningEntity: GroupAssignment)
The Solution class gets a mutableSetOf Students, Lecturers and some configurations (min./max. number of participants/students for a group, optimal groupsize and weighted keywords) for solving.

The result for my test

```
    @Test
    fun lessThanMinGroupSize() {
    val students = Student().generateStudents(2)
    val configuration = Configuration(3, 9, 5, specialKeywords)

    val lecturer = mutableSetOf(
    Lecturer("4664807", mutableListOf(KeyWord("kotlin"), KeyWord("logistics"), KeyWord("java"), KeyWord("bigdata"), KeyWord("c")), mutableListOf("BIN", "BWI", "BEC"),
        mutableListOf(LocalDate.parse("2021-08-05"), LocalDate.parse("2021-08-08")),
        false, true))

    constraintVerifier.verifyThat(GroupAssignmentConstraintProvider::minGroupSize)
        .given(students, lecturer, configuration)
        .penalizes()
}
```

using the minGroupSize-Constraint:

```
    fun minGroupSize(constraintFactory: ConstraintFactory): Constraint {
    return constraintFactory
        .from(GroupAssignment::class.java)
        .groupBy(GroupAssignment::group, count())
        .filter { group, number ->
            number < group!!.minsize
        }
        .penalize("group min Conflict", ofHard(medium))
}
```

tells me:
(GroupAssignmentTest.kt:65 refers to the `.penalizes()` in the Test)

> java.lang.AssertionError: Broken expectation.

> Constraint: groupAssignment.solver/group min Conflict

> Explanation of score (0hard/0soft):

> Constraint match totals:

> Indictments:

> Expected penalty but there was none.

> at org.optaplanner.test.impl.score.stream.DefaultSingleConstraintAssertion.assertMatch(DefaultSingleConstraintAssertion.java:185)
> at org.optaplanner.test.impl.score.stream.DefaultSingleConstraintAssertion.penalizes(DefaultSingleConstraintAssertion.java:82)
> at org.optaplanner.test.api.score.stream.SingleConstraintAssertion.penalizes(SingleConstraintAssertion.java:121)
> at GroupAssignmentTest.lessThanMinGroupSize(GroupAssignmentTest.kt:65)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:205)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:201)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)

Apart from that, the constraints work.

I guess, I'm not initializing or using the ConstraintVerifier the right way. Is there anyone who can help me to solve the problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your test. First of all:

```
        .given(students, lecturer, configuration)
```

the `given()` call expects individual instances. You are giving it collections of instances, specifically a  mutable set of students. Your constraint does not do `from(Set.class)` or anything of the like, and therefore it will not see these instances. You'll have to either enumerate your students, or don't give them at all, since your constraint does neither `from()` nor `join()` on a student class.

Furthermore, your constraint does `from(GroupAssignment.class)`, yet I see no `GroupAssignment`s among your `given()` arguments. Once again, the constraint stream has nothing to start from, and therefore the assertion message is correct - there was nothing to penalize.

Comment: Additionally to Lukas's answer, take a look at `TimeTableConstraintProviderTest.kt` in https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts

Comment: thank you for your hints, I found out how to put it right!